# Load a string of markdown properties as JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, parsing, object, markdown

Given a string I need to create an object and convert that string to properties.

So given this:

```
"anchor: true,
text: 'primary button',
style: 'primary'
"
```

I need to generate a real object:

```
{
     anchor: true,
     text: 'primary button',
     style: 'primary'
}
```

Any help on this of course greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you create valid JSON strings, this would be trivial, now you'd made into a nightmare and have to write your own parser.

Comment: (This will probably go better if showing an attempt - and the problem(s) that results from it - or at least pointing out approaches explored and why they are not suitable.)

Comment: @adeneo But MD/YAML != JSON.

Comment: `anObject=eval("0||{"+yourString+"}")`

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the markdown format.
If it is Yaml (which it looks like), you will need to use a yaml parser such as js-yaml (https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml).

Comment: Thank you but the markdown is not relevant. It is just where the string is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dandavis for posting this answer in a comment:

```
anObject=eval("0||{"+yourString+"}")
```

Comment: I couldn't bring myself to put eval() in an answer, and i would probably get beat up if i did. A lot of people don't like eval for a lot of reasons, most of them trivial, but some worth considering. I would say that as long as you don't eval() user input, and you don't need to run with "es3 compact profile"-level support (ala chrome extensions), eval() will be the simplest way to do what you want with controlled input.